# Data axis (y-axis) to the right in Crystal Report 2013 developer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

How to move the y-axis to the right hand side in Visual Studio 2013, Crystal Report 2013 developer? Not sure if this is a feature available in this CR developer version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean axis on chart? Right-click on chart, Chart options, Grid, Axis on Right - in your CR version this could be in some other dialog/place of course, but in Chart options anyway.

/edit/
For newer CR, some things are changed. To change axis placement, you have to click/select some label on this axis and choose "Data(y-axis) Options" from label context menu. If label is not selected, you don't have this menu at all.

Comment: In my Visual Studio 2013, Crystal Report 2013, right click > Chart Options will show Template, General and Titles tab. Upon clicking the General menu item, I checked in all tab (including Gridlines), but there are no Axis on Right option... maybe I need not use Visual Studio 2013 for report creation/editing? Maybe this is only available in the standalone CR installation?

Comment: I have older (standalone) CR, not VS2013 one. I'll try to find some VS version here, maybe this option is in some other place; internally report format should be same (and this option present).

Comment: I added some info, maybe helps :)

Comment: I just downloaded the CT 2013 standalone version and can confirm that it is available in the standalone version, and not in the visual studio 2013, CR 2013 developer version... thanks for the help.

Comment: Strange difference actually - this doesn't seem one of these things, which make customer buy standalone version; maybe they (SAP) think differently. Thanks for clearing up this question!